# Get from string with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to extract from string

> `userAllowedCrud['create']`
>   the part that is inside `[]`.

i think using regular expression is the better way to do it. Am i wrong?

Comment: _“i think using regular expression is the better way to do it”_ - for one thing to be better than another, you need at least two things ... so, what would the second/the others?

Answer (score 1):

For the example string, you could use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) which will return an array and specify the single quote `'` as the separator.

Your value will be the second item in the array.

```js
var string = "userAllowedCrud['create']";
console.log(string.split("'")[1]);
```

If you want to use a regex you could use:
[`^[^\[]+\['([^']+)']$`](https://regex101.com/r/olUiUB/1) or [`\['([^']+)']`](https://regex101.com/r/olUiUB/2)

Your value will be in group 1

The first regex will match:

```
^       # Begin of the string
[^[]+   # Match not [ one or more times
['      # Match ['
(       # Capture in a group (group 1)
  [^']+ # Match not a ' one or more times
)       # Close capturing group
']      # Match ']
$       # End of the string
```

The second regex captures in a group what is between `['']` without `^` and `$`

```js
var string = "userAllowedCrud['create']";
var pattern1 = /^[^\[]+\['([^']+)']$/;
var pattern2 = /\['([^']+)']/
console.log(string.match(pattern1)[1]);
console.log(string.match(pattern2)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression like: `/\[([^\]]*)\]/`. `\[` means match a `[`, `\]` means match a `]`, `[^\]]*` means match 0 or more of any character that is not a close bracket.

```js
console.log(
    "userAllowedCrud['create']".match(/\[([^\]]*)\]/)[1]
);

// Output:
// 'create'
```

If you need what is inside the quotes inside the brackets there are many solutuions, for example:

```js
// for single and double quotes
"userAllowedCrud['create']".match(/\[([^\]]*)\]/)[1].slice(1, -1)

// Or (for single and double quotes):
"userAllowedCrud['create']".match(/\[("|')([^\]]*)\1\]/)[2]

// Or (for single and double quotes):
"userAllowedCrud['create']".match(/\[(["'])([^\]]*)\1\]/)[2]

// Or (for single quotes):
"userAllowedCrud['create']".match(/\['([^\]]*)'\]/)[1]

// Or (for double quotes):
"userAllowedCrud['create']".match(/\['([^\]]*)'\]/)[1]
```

There are many other methods, these are just a few. 
I'd recommend looking into learning regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3533202

Comment: Thanks @scagood . But i need it without ' just the create not 'create'

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos - You could use something like: `.match(/\[(["'])([^\]]*)\1\]/)[2]`. instead. I would strongly recommend looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3533202 for more information on regex

Answer (score 0):

Try to use javascript string operation

```
let tempString = "userAllowedCrud['create']";
let key = str => str.substring(
    str.indexOf("'") + 1,
    str.lastIndexOf("'")
);
console.log(key(tempString))
```